# How to save the new record using existing record?

Tags: django-rest-framework

For Instance I have an Model called **Demo Model** with 100 fields, I have queried and got one particular record and stored in variable called *demo_values* and want to create a new record using demo_values dynamically.

How can we create it?

Answer (score 2):

```
demo_object = DemoModel.objects.first()
demo_object.pk = None
demo_object.save()
```

This should create a copy of the model object with exact same data.

Comment: I said i want to create a new record using existing record, but you are updating the existing record.

Comment: I'm not updating the existing object. By setting pk to `None` it creates completely different object. Please try it and see pk for both records.

Comment: Thanx a lot @mariodev